# Using existing JMS libraries with a AMQP broker (RabbitMQ)

Tags: spring, jms, rabbitmq, amqp

We use RabbitMQ and Spring-AMQP for our messaging system.

However there are many Java libraries that use JMS that I would rather not rewrite to AMQP.

I failed to Google a JMS client that will use AMQP.

Should I just rewrite the library to use AMQP directly?

Comment: Could you please provide a little feedback here in the comments on what solution worked for you in the end?  Or alternatively if you went with something different, could you post an answer?  In researching this question myself I couldn't come up with a better answer than @nos did without doing a bunch of testing.  I'd really like to gain from your experiences here.

Comment: @Ben Burns I just used AMQP directly through Springs AMQP abstraction. In theory you could build a JMS layer on top of that but I never did. http://www.springsource.org/spring-amqp

Answer (score 3):

[qpid](http://qpid.apache.org/) , which also speaks amqp , has a JMS client library. Perhaps that also works with rabbitmq.

There's some (old) [indications](http://lists.rabbitmq.com/pipermail/rabbitmq-discuss/2009-March/003167.html) the [OpenAMQ](http://www.openamq.org) library works works with rabbitmq

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you're actually building, you'll probably find that Spring Integration is useful:

http://www.springsource.org/spring-integration

It abstracts the concepts of end points, such that they are pluggable and there is built-in support for JMS & AMQP.

It's fairly trivial to build a simple AMQP <-> JMS adapter.